# Looking for marriage record of Albert Augur near Bermondsey (London) around 1870?

Tags: 19th-century, england, marriage-records, london

Albert Augur is my 3rd great grandfather. I have been able to find records for my other English ancestors with ease, but he seems to be a tough nut to crack. Anyway, I will list what I know about him below.

- He had a son in 1870 or 1871, Bermondsey, London called George Henry Augur. George also appears on the 1911 Census with his wife and kids.
- Albert appears on George's marriage record as his father, but no mother is mentioned.
- I have not found a birth record for George either, and that might help me to find his mother too.

I know this isn't much information, but it's all I have.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  I'm going to  focus your question on just finding candidate marriage records and encourage you to ask new questions seeking birth/baptism and death/burial records for him, and a birth/baptism record for George.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 1881 census shows Albert and Emma Auger with their son George, living in Rotherhithe, London (see RG 11/578, f 25, p 43):

[image]

The marriage register of Albert Augur to Emma Winter can be found in [London, England, Church of England Marriages and Banns, 1754-1921](http://search.ancestry.co.uk/search/db.aspx?dbid=1623) on Ancestry.co.uk:

> 2 Sep 1878, Bermondsey St Paul, Surrey, after banns: Albert Augur, 35,
>   bachelor, lumper, of 34 Russell St, Bermondsey, s. of John Augur,
>   shoemaker, married Emma Winter, 25, spinster, of 13 Renforth St,
>   Rotherhithe, d. of Robert Winter, engineer. Witnessed by William
>   Clements and Pheobe Clements.

Of course, if Albert and Emma were married in 1878, and George was born in c.1872, there's really just a couple options:

- George was Emma's son born out of wedlock (perhaps registered as Winter)
- George was born to a previous wife/partner of Albert (unlikely to be a previous wife since he was a bachelor in 1878)
- George was adopted

I would caution against making leaps back to Albert and Emma's ancestry before you have confirmed George's parentage. You first need to work out whether Albert and/or Emma were really parents of George, given the conflicting dates of birth and marriage. George's birth may be registered under an unexpected surname.

Answer (score 2):

Using FindMyPast.co.uk I searched for any records with name Albert Augur (and variants) born in 1845 +/- 5 years at Bermondsey and two were found:

- Albert Agur is in the 1871 census living as a Lodger (aged 21, born in Surrey) in the household of George Smith at Alice Street in the parish of St Mary Magdalen Bermondsey.
- Albert Augur married either Louisa Ann Turner or Emma Winter in the 3rd Quarter of 1878 in the district of St Olave Southwark

I think both of these records appear to be likely matches for the man you seek.

Also of interest, from Ancestry.com, may be three certificates for Albert Augur in the `All UK and Ireland, Masters and Mates Certificates, 1850-1927` which all say that he was born in Maidenhead, Berkshire, England:

- Second Mate on 16 Oct 1863 at London, aged 20
- Only Mate on 8 Feb 1872 at Dundee, aged 29
- Master on 11 Mar 1876 at London, aged 33

These records are consistent with this Albert Augur being born about 1843 at Maidenhead.

I think these records probably all belong to the same man and that the 1871 Census recording of him being born in Surrey (and his age there) may be considered less reliable than the information on the certificates.

Going back to FindMyPast and searching for Albert Augur born about 1843 at Maidenhead reveals him (aged 7, born about 1844 at Maidenhead) in the 1851 Census at Folly Hill, Cookham, Berkshire, England living with his parents John (Shoemaker, Employing 14 Men) and Henrietta, and four siblings.